# C++ is creating a header to solve circular dependency a good idea?

Tags: c++, header-files, circular-dependency

I have a C++ project that's starting to get big. I'm facing a situation where I have lots of classes with circular dependencies. Suppose I have classes A, B, C, D. To solve this, I've created a header file named **circular_dep.h**

This file's content would be pointers to classes:

```
class A;
class B;
class C;
class D;
```

This header is included by all my classes's header now. That way, the compiler stopped complaining when I had circular dependencies. Whenever I add a new class to the project, however, I'll have to add it to **circular_dep.h**

I couldn't find any easier way to do this, so to me this is the best solution so far. My question is: is it a good idea to apply to projects that might face circular dependency issues? Or is this a bad design/bad or dangerous practice?

Comment: Circular references are best avoided all together. You might be better off asking how to re-structure your code such that you won't need them in the first place. Also note that the header file you're showing doesn't contain *pointers* but (forward) *declarations* of the classes.

Comment: My preference would be to just have the individual class forward references in the headers that need them. But it is just a preference. One reason not to put it all in one header is to prevent having to recompile everything when you add a class.

Comment: In my head, some cases may be inevitable. For example, I'm writing a compiler for a simple language that looks like C. A function has a block (anything between '{' and '}'). a block has variable declarations and commands (like 'if') and a command might have a block ('if' may have a block). Thus, we have a circ dep issue between Command and Block

Comment: These are not pointers to classes. They are forward declarations of classes. I don't see a reason to create another header file for this when you can just write the forward declaration itself whenever needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is fine. The naming suffix I've usually seen is `_fwd.h`/`_fwd.hpp`/`_fwd.hxx` or whatever variant of `.h` you like. You can see this in Boost, for example: [optional_fwd.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/optional/optional_fwd.hpp).

(Of course reducing circular dependencies is a good goal, but some things are mutually-recursive in nature, like grammars, so you have no choice.)